# Instead of url how to use it in assets android by using volley?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I don't have server to display and fetch data using json. So how to call from assets instead of using url android?

```
private String URL_FEED = "http://feed.json"; // i just using feed url json directly in assets.
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("yourfilename.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

// making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    loadJSONFromAsset(), null, new Response.Listener() {
              }

I called by using loadJSONFromAsset method to display it. But it's not displaying. If I give link directly, datas been fetched and displaying. Please explain how to use json in assets by using volley android? Any example using volley from assets in json been helpful

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to use volley when you have your `JSON` located in device? It does not make sence for me.